# rm does not support long-form --recursive, --force on Mac?

Tags: terminal

This seems crazy, but I just checked in a build script that switched from `rm -rf` to `rm --recursive --force`, since it would be more readable. And a collaborator who uses a Mac is reporting this breaks. When I ask him to run `rm --help`, he gets

```
5gt2:html-build annevk$ rm --help
rm: illegal option -- -
usage: rm [-f | -i] [-dPRrvW] file ...
       unlink file

5gt2:html-build annevk$ rm --force
rm: illegal option -- -
usage: rm [-f | -i] [-dPRrvW] file ...
       unlink file
```

This seems crazy to me that such a basic thing would not be supported across different *nixes. Does anyone have a workaround, or at least an explanation?

Comment: You really think `rm --recursive --force` is *more* readable than `rm -rf`? Verbosity ≠ readability, especially not when `rm -rf` is so deeply ingrained in the minds of Unix users everywhere.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

OSX is Unix and uses the BSD tools. The extended names are a GNU extension.

You just need to use the standard parameters e.g. -r -f 
(These are in the [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/rm.html))

The error is in the build file using non standard Unix commands

Answer (score 4):

`rm` packaged with OS X is the BSD `rm` which conforms to the [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/rm.html). It looks like you were expecting GNU `rm`.

IIRC, long options are more of a GNU thing.

Comment: FWIW, OS X users can `brew install coreutils` and then use `grm`. But portable code should just use `-rf`.